# Coding k-means algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Could you help me to write matlab simple code for k-means algorithm **without using the algorithm in matlab toolbox** ? So i want to work with array and plot the clusters with unique colors. For example i have an array=[1 2; 3 4 ; 5 6] with 2 clusters; some points will be red some points are blue at the end the program should plot the array in axis. then using the k-means algorithm. at the end. plot clusters in graphical interface.
can you help me?

Comment: Did you copy & paste this straight from somewhere else? Please not that StackOverflow is not a place to find others who do your work, but get help with a specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see how MATLAB does it, type

```
edit kmeans
```

into the command window. This might give you some hints.

An easier place to start would probably be the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), which has the basic algorithm succinctly outlined.